# How to solve process.nextTick error?

Tags: javascript, tcp, node.js, epoll

I am using node.js to build a TCP server and I got the following errors. How to solve this?

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: ETIMEDOUT, Connection timed out
    at Socket._readImpl (net.js:163:14)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:631:22)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
```

Comment: Your connection timed out, we need more information then this. It probably means either your client or server crashed or your TCP port is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try handling the 'error' event on the TCP server you created. All unhandled 'error' events cause an unhandled exception on node.js